# Data-Annotations - EntityValidation removal based on condition in code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have a column that is Required in my model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The Name field is required")]
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

However, is it only required on different conditions.

So I remove the `ModelState` Key when the correct condition is met

```
if (Status_ID != 2 && Status_ID != 3)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Name");
}
```

Which works, but when EF tries to save the entity, I get a `EntityVaildationError` because I am guessing I have the `Data Annotation`"Required" on the property which can never been taken off programmatically regardless of the `ModelState`

How else could I achieve what I want?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with the existing `RequiredAttribute`.

However, you can implement your own custom conditional validation attribute.

Here are some links to guide you in the right direction:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/09/29/mvc-validationtookit-alpha-release-conditional-validation-with-mvc-3.aspx

Once you implement your custom `RequiredIf` conditional validation attribute you can set the condition like:

```
public class ValidationSample
{
   [RequiredIf("PropertyValidationDependsOn", true)]
   public string PropertyToValidate { get; set; }

   public bool PropertyValidationDependsOn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, way ahead of ya! I am doing my own RequiredOn Attribute, but having trouble with the value parameter in the override isValid method being null! so learning now :)

Comment: Great!.. i am glad you figured it out ;)

Comment: Thanks, but how do you pass in a property into the attribute? like

`public int Status_ID{get; set:}`

`[RequiredOn(ID = Status_ID, ErrorMessage = "The Name field is required")] `

I dont want to hardcode a ID.

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518291/how-to-pass-compiler-checked-property-names-expression-tree-to-a-custom-attrib

Comment: Ok the above can be done by going too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713281/attribute-dependent-on-another-field

How I done what I wanted, if anyone else wants to know if using the same logic, give us a comment and I will help :)